# Are there any "forbidden" functions in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Some time ago, while searching for a book on complex analysis I came across one in which the author said the book wasn't going to deal with functions of some kind, but then proceeded to give examples instead of a definition, from which I couldn't grasp the point he was trying to make, but I remember it had to do with certain algebraic combinations of $x$ and $y$ (for the complex variable $z=x+iy=(x,y)$). But now I can't find the book, and in all the other books i've searched I can't find a warning paragraph like this.

Now, having actually started reading a book on complex analysis (Stewart & Tall), I was a bit skeptic when the function $f$ was written as $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued functions, because I can't see why this is always possible, I mean, because the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$, $f(z)$ can always be written as $a+ib$ for any $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$, and if $z=x+iy$ then surely $a$ and $b$ will depend on $x$ and $y$ (right?). But i'm not sure this would be a proof of the existence of $u$ and $v$, no matter how the $x$'s and $y$'s are algebraically (or otherwise) combined, and I can't help but think it has to do with what the other book was warning about. It feels like cheating just to write $f(z)=Re(f(z))+iIm(f(z))$ although defining $u=Re \circ f$ and $v= Im \circ f$ also feels completely valid, I'm very confused.

I still think this must be true because reading a bit further I found the Cauchy-Riemman equations which explicitly use $u$ and $v$, but if this is not a problem, what possibly could be the functions the book was talking about? Are there any combinations of $x$ and $y$ which determine functions that are "not allowed" in complex analysis? Or any other "forbidden" functions? Or maybe the author was a bit crazy?

P.S. I'm sorry if the title made the question look more interesting than it actually is. Also, for my background, I'm a first year maths student, and this is my first post.

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel the decomposition $$f(a+bi)=\mathfrak{Re}(f(a+bi))+\mathfrak{Im}(f(a+bi))$$ to be cheating; it's absolutely valid, and - as the Cauchy-Riemann equations show - is often useful.

Comment: There isn't anything special about $u$ and $v$, they are just abstract functions defined to be what they have to be. You say "surely $a$ and $b$ will depend on $x$ and $y$" and that's exactly right: $u$ and $v$ are functions each depending on both $x$ and $y$. Pick $x$ and $y$, this gives you (unique) $a$ and $b$, send $u(x,y)$ to $a$ and $v(x,y)$ to $b$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is worthwhile to remark that both $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ can be written explicitly in terms of $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$.  That is, $x=\frac12(z+\bar z)$ and $y=\frac1{i2}(z-\bar z)$.  So, more precisely, $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=f(z,\bar z)$.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm not sure what that means - $f$ is a *unary* function, not a binary function, so $f(z,\overline{z})$ is ill-formed. I don't think that what you've written is more precise at all.

Comment: As to the main question, a text choosing not to deal with certain kinds of functions doesn't mean that those functions are in any way forbidden; rather, it means that the author has made a choice of focus.

Comment: @NoahSchweber As I wrote, let $x=\frac12(z+\bar z)$ and $y=\frac1{i2}(z-\bar z)$ and substitute into $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.  That gives a new function of $z$ and $\bar z$.  This applies well to the Wirtinger derivative.

Comment: @MarkViola OK, but that new function isn't $f$ itself (the OP has already used the symbol $f$ to refer to the function $x+yi\mapsto u(x+iy)+v(x+iy)i$). Rather, what that shows is that the original $f$ can be thought of as the restriction of a different function $\hat{f}$ of two complex variables  - or better, that the original $f$ is equal to the composition of $\hat{f}$ with the map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^2:z\mapsto (z,\overline{z})$. And while that's true, I don't really see how it's useful to the OP here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Again, if you review my first comment, it began with "It is worthwhile to remark ..."  Of course, that was my opinion only.

Answer (score 1):

If, for each $x,y\in\Bbb R$ in the domain $D_f$ of $f$, you define $u(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}f(x+yi)$ and $v(x,y)=\operatorname{Im}f(x+yi)$, then $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions and$$(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R):x+yi\in D_f\implies f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i.$$

Comment: One thing to remark is that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ can be written in terms of $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$.  So, more precisely, $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=f(z,\bar z)$.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm not sure what that means - $f$ is a *unary* function, not a binary function, so $f(z,\overline{z})$ is ill-formed.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I thought that we covered this in your post.  I'll repeat here.  For any function of $x$ and $y$, we make a transformation $x\mapsto \frac12(z+\bar z)$ and $y\mapsto \frac1{i2}(z-\bar z)$.  That results in a function of $z$ and $\bar z$.